# loadJSON only loads some objects

Tags: php, jquery, html, sql, ajax

The JSON seems to load into the array ok and it loads into the plain text objects.

The checkbox shows checked ON even though the data clearly shows its a 0

The data does not load at all

The plain text works great

Here is the JSON

```
[{"0":"0","drscomplete":"0","1":"2016-03-12","drsremind":"2016-03-12","2":"db","drsby":"db"}]
```

This works:

```
   <input  name="drsby" type="text" id="drsby"  readonly   />
```

This load checked ON even though the data says 0:

```
 <input   name="drscomplete" type="checkbox" id="drscomplete" value="1"   />
```

and this doesnt load at all:

```
<input name="drsremind"   type="date"  id="drsremind" />
```

Here is the php that does the load:

```
jQuery.ajax({
url: "dealfinalizeload.php",
data:'id='+id,
type: "POST",
success:function(data){

        var data2 = $.parseJSON(data);
        $('div#white_content_dealfinalize').loadJSON(data2);

        alert(data);

}, 
error:function (){
    alert("Error loading tasks");
    }
});
```

this is the php that load the JSON

```
 $SQL ="SELECT drscomplete, drsremind ,drsby from dealfinalize d where d.ID=" . $id;

$resultArray = array();
$result = mysqli_query($con,$SQL);
if($result->num_rows >0 ) 
    $resultArray = mysqli_fetch_all($result,MYSQLI_BOTH);
echo json_encode($resultArray);
```

Any ideas what I did wrong?

Comment: I don't think we've got enough context, here.
Also, it looks like you're overloading the purpose of the object inside of the array. `{ 0: "some value", 1: "other value", property: "another value", anotherProperty; "more values" }` What is the purpose of this object? Do you intend to iterate over indices (in which case they should probably be separate objects/values inside of an array), do you intend to enumerate over keys (why are the 0 and 1 on the same level)? And what tech are you using to interpolate into the `<?=$drsby?>` it looks like PHP, but I don't want to assume.

Comment: I removed the php <?=$drsby?> in the example above.  I dont know how else to load the array. I added the code I am using above.  However the one field does load ok. And the date and checkbox do not. Thats the weird part.  So if the array was loaded wrong with the indexes it seems to work! ??